# Jquery: Action for each change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Continuing on from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649933/jquery-on-form-change-with-bootstrap-sliders/16650319?noredirect=1

I am currently using the below to capture the ID of a slider and change the content of #log.  The problem with this is that is only capture the first slider.  I need this to be actioned when any slider is changed.

I've tried using the ID of price on all my sliders, however this doesn't work.

```
$('#price').each(function(index,value){
    $(this).bind('slide', function(){
        $("#log").prepend('<p>Changed</p>')
    });
});
```

Comment: Using the same ID on multiple elements is a *bad bad* idea. Use a class instead.

Comment: not only is it a bad idea, it violates the html specification. use class names instead.

Comment: i already said the same thing there.He posted the same question with in hour

Comment: The `$('#price')` selector will only get you the first element matching that. If you need all elements, use `$('[id="price"]')` instead. But don't. Use classes instead as in PSR's answer for the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because JavaScript conforms with the HTML specification, and the HTML specification states that **[ID attributes must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)**.

You aren't allowed to have two elements with `id="price"`. Because of this JavaScript will stop searching after it has found the first match. Your `.each()` loop will only go around once, regardless of how many `#price` elements are present after the first.

To resolve this, use classes instead. For example:

```
<div class="price">...</div>
<div class="price">...</div>
<div class="price">...</div>
```

```
$('.price').each(function(index,value) { ... });
```

You will also need to change your `#log` elements to use classes, too.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#price')` is id, page include one duplicate id. you need use class